# Insert into two tables, one having foreign key of the other

Tags: php, mysql

I've looked at similar problems in SO and most of the solution were .NET centric and/or using stored procedures. So little help there. This is a snippet of the backend that I'm using to address an issue in my application.

```
$executestat=0;
//-------------------------
//PHASE-1
$sql = "INSERT INTO first_table (a_name,a_type,a_location) 
values('".$a_name."','".$a_type."','".$a_location."')";
if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
    $executestat=$executestat+1;
}
//-------------------------

//-------------------------
//PHASE-2
$sql = "SELECT f.a_id
from first_table as f
order by f.f_id desc limit 1";
if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
    $executestat=$executestat+1;
}
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $max_a_id = $row["a_id"];
    }
}else{$executestat=$executestat-1;}
//-------------------------

//-------------------------
//PHASE-3
$sql = "INSERT INTO second_table (a_id,b_title,b_location) 
values('".$max_a_id."','".$b_title."','".$b_location."')";
if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
    $executestat=$executestat+1;
}
//-------------------------
```

### Problem Description:

- From a single form, I am trying to insert data into **first_table** and **second_table**
- **second_table** has the field `a_id` which is the foreign-key from **first_table**. (`a_id` is auto-increment primary-key on the **first_table**)

### How I'm handling it right now:

I have been told that this type of problem is handled, generally, by querying the **first_table**, in the second query, to get the most recent `id` and then using it, while inserting data in the third query, to insert into the **second_table**.

### Whats going wrong

I took this advice from somebody who's been dealing with databases for a long time. I don't know if it's something I'm doing because, occasionally, only the first query runs ***(or so I think*)***, failing the other queries completely.

- *(or so I think) : because the success condition is `if($executestat==3)` . So I know that the first-query runs(because the Db gets updated with the **first_table** insertion) but I'm not sure if the second query is running or not. However, I do know that **atleast one but not all** queries are running. **Is there a way to echo errors into a file in PHP. That'd be great for this**
- *Also, before anyone points out, I'll tackle the SQL injection problem with prepared statements later. I just need advice on this, now.*

### tl;dr

- Trying to insert two tables, one with foreign-key `a_id` of the other.
- Handled this by inserting first_table in the first query, finding out max `a_id` in the second query, using `$max_a_id` to insert into second_table in the third query.
- Sometimes this is unexpectedly failing. I know that atleast one but not all queries execute because first_table has new data inserted into it in the Db, but second_table, which should have a concurrent data pertaining to the first insertion, does not.
- How do I send echo of error to a file so that I can catch exactly where everything is failing?
- Is finding out `$max_a_id` a bad approach? Can anyone tell me a better way?

> Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? A small snippet (modification of this; even better is complete revamp)

Comment: You know you can just get the last inserted id, instead of using an extra query for it right?

Comment: @Naruto . I did not know or even consider that possibility. Thanks! Will test it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your insert, use `$mysqli->insert_id;` to get inserted value.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO first_table (a_name,a_type,a_location) 
values('".$a_name."','".$a_type."','".$a_location."')";
if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
    $executestat=$executestat+1;
}
$max_a_id = $conn->insert_id;
//----
```